# Regexp in nginx config (server_name)

Tags: regex, nginx

I try to write regexp for nginx config.
That's url examples:

```
api.drive.pss.np.sweetdev.com
api.google.pss.np.sweetdev.com
api.mail.pss.np.sweetdev.com
api.google.alex.np.sweetdev.com
api.mail.alex.np.sweet-dev.com
```

I want to extract second and third part to variables **site_name** and **user_name**.

That's my tries (only for second part):

```
server_name ~^api\.([a-z]+)\.pss\.np\.sweetdev\.com$;
server_name ~^api\.(?<site_name>\w+)\.pss\.np\.sweetdev\.com$;
```

Why it's not working?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in perl based on your input make use of it.

#!/usr/bin/perl

```
use strict;
my $server_name = qq(api.drive.pss.np.sweetdev.com
api.google.pss.np.sweetdev.com
api.mail.pss.np.sweetdev.com
api.google.alex.np.sweetdev.com
api.mail.alex.np.sweet-dev.com);


my (@site_name, @user_name) = $server_name =~ m{api\.([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)\.np\.sweet-?dev\.com}ig;

print join("\n",@site_name,@user_name);
```